# Go checking login values before login

Tags: html, postgresql, go

I got a login form, when I click on send, I redirect the page to a `/create`. There I check in a GO function if the values of my login are the correct to give access to the next page, but I have a problem with my function.

loginCheck:

```
func loginCheck(w http.ResponseWriter, r* http.Request){
        r.ParseForm()

        //Call the DB function
        db:= SetupDB()

        name, password := r.FormValue("user"), r.FormValue("password")
        hashedPassword, err := bcrypt.GenerateFromPassword([]byte(password), bcrypt.DefaultCost)
        PanicIf(err)

        rows, err := db.Query("SELECT name, password from users where name = $1 and password = $2" ,name, hashedPassword)
        PanicIf(err)

        defer rows.Close()

        for rows.Next() {

            err := rows.Scan(&name, &hashedPassword)
            PanicIf(err)

               fmt.Println(name, hashedPassword)
        }


        db.Close()
}
```

Im trying to print the values inside the rows.Next() to see if read the values from the database but it's empty.

Comment: I am guessing you are using http://godoc.org/code.google.com/p/go.crypto/bcrypt
This is not how bcrypt works. Use the [bcrypt.CompareHashAndPassword()](http://godoc.org/code.google.com/p/go.crypto/bcrypt#CompareHashAndPassword) function. Every time you use `GenerateFromPassword`, it creates a random salt, and you can't compare those values.

Comment: @seong Thank you seong, I didnt knew that. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To add to [seong](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3460555/seong)'s [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24756912/go-checking-login-values-before-login/24757303#comment38411673_24756912), you can consider [this example in goserver](https://github.com/sycoso/goserver/blob/b948b6cc162efe06b60bbd0bdc6011966e162f8e/password.go#L10-L32):

```
func CheckPassword(username, password string) bool {
    if len(username) == 0 || len(password) == 0 {
        return false
    }

    var hashPw []byte
    err := DB.QueryRow("SELECT password FROM users WHERE username=?", username).Scan(&hashPw)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("CheckPassword", err.Error())
        return false
    }

    if len(hashPw) == 0 {
        return false
    }

    err = bcrypt.CompareHashAndPassword(hashPw, []byte(password))
    if err == nil {
        return true
    }
    return false
}
```

The query is done using only `username`.